# ajax:beforeSend getting triggered on any ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-ui

I am trying to bing ajax:beforeSend, ajax:error and ajax:complete to my rails form which gets submitted remotely.

I am tried using delegate, bind, live etc but i am still facing the same issue.

```
$('form#contact_form').bind('ajax:beforeSend', function(evt, xhr, settings) {
  //getItemIds(); added this call on button click
  call();
})
.bind('ajax:error', function(event, request, settings) {
  text();
})
.bind('ajax:complete', function(event, request, settings) {
  phone();
});
```

I have other anchor links on the page which also make ajax calls but for any ajax call made the the form "beforesend" function is getting called. i want to call it only for that specific form.

When i do alert(event.target.id); inside the ajaxBeforesend i see an id of element for which i have not binded the ajax call

**`I am targeting only a specific form so how that before send be triggered for other links? Can anyone tell what is that i am doing wrong, Thanks.`**

**`NOTE: When i commented out the jquery_ui.js this behaviour stopped happening. Is is some conflict issue, Please help.`**

Comment: Is the form dynamic?

Comment: Yes it is, its a Rails form

Answer (score 1):

You are binding your form to ANY ajax call that may happen, which means that if something else in the background that may be using ajax, would trigger your call, not just for the form you intend on catching.

The best way of preventing anything from running form specific binds, is to, on button click (something you didn't include, but I assume you have a button on the form somewhere that actions the submit) to do this on button click and not bind to form:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: url,
    data: data,
    beforeSend: function() {
        call();
    },
    success: function(data) {
        //something
    },
    error: function(xhr) { // if error occured
        text();
    },
    complete: function() { 
        phone();        
    }
});
```

If this doesn't help, please update your original post with more information. I sincerely hope this helps.

Comment: hi thanks for your answer, when i do alert(event.target.id); inside the ajaxBeforesend i see an id of element for which i have not binded the ajax call.

Comment: I am a bit confused, is this the right behaviour. I am targeting only a specific form so how that beforesend be triggered for other links?

Comment: Is the ajax command wrapped in the .on('click') of the submit button? if it's picking up other elements then it's not binding correclty for some reason. Remember if you bind the beforeSend to the form, it will pick up ANY pre-ajax call, even unrelated ones

Comment: no its not bound on the onclick, but this is surprising as to even when i bind ajax before send to form it picking on other elements to, is this written some where in documentation or is it a bug in Jquery. Can you point me to some documentation for the same, Thanks a lot.

Comment: No it's not a bug in jquery as far as I know, but there could be stuff happening in the background that you're picking up on. I would recommend just binding to the onclick of the submit button so it runs in context of the form you're wanting to post/manipulate

Comment: ok thanks, will try doing that. also other thing i noticed was when i comment out Jquery ui file, everything works as expected, could it be related?

Comment: it could be, I don't know if jquery UI does ajax requests for any reason. Are you using a template or something you did yourself?

Comment: using jquwry_ujs and a few custom javascrips and also bootstrap framework

Comment: get yourself fiddler and see what ajax calls happens when you comment in jquery ui

Comment: sure, thanks a lot for your help. Your answer was certainly helpful. upvoting it